# Guyss im new to android i dont know how to pop up dialog in recyclerview. i.e when i click in items , its should pop up Alertdialog saying edit option

Tags: android

```
public class MyDriverActivityTimelineRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyDriverActivityTimelineRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    //    Data references
    public List<DriverState> driverStates;
    private Context context;
    private SimpleDateFormat timelineDateFormat;
    private SimpleDateFormat timelineTimeFormat, sdf, hourdf;
    private  String start_time, end_time;
    private Date d1 = null, d2 = null;
    private Drawable drawable;
    String since;
    int cal, n;
    private long xyz, abc, diffHours = 0;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    //    Listener references
    private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MyDriverActivityTimelineRecyclerViewAdapter(List<DriverState> driverStates, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener, Context context) {
        this.driverStates = driverStates;
        mListener = listener;
        this.context = context;
        timelineDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
        timelineTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_driveractivitytimeline, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.driverState = driverStates.get(position);
        switch (driverStates.get(position).getState()) {
            case DriverState.STATE_OFFLINE:
                holder.mIdView.setText(R.string.off_duty);
                drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_remove_circle_outline_black_24dp);
                drawable.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red));
                holder.timelineView.setMarker(drawable);
                break;

            case DriverState.STATE_ONLINE:
                holder.mIdView.setText(R.string.on_duty);
                drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_check_circle_black_24dp);
                drawable.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green));
                holder.timelineView.setMarker(drawable);
                break;

            case DriverState.STATE_SLEEPER:
                holder.mIdView.setText(R.string.sleeper);
                drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_airline_seat_individual_suite_black_24dp);
                drawable.setTint(Color.BLACK);
                holder.timelineView.setMarker(drawable);
                break;

            case DriverState.STATE_DRIVING:
                holder.mIdView.setText(R.string.driving);
                drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_drive_eta_black_24dp);
                drawable.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.orange));
                holder.timelineView.setMarker(drawable);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (position + 1 == driverStates.size()) {
            holder.timelineView.initLine(0);
        }

        holder.mContentView.setText(driverStates.get(position).getLocationAddress());

        if (position == 0) {
            holder.tv_driverstate_date.setText(timelineDateFormat.format(holder.driverState.getEventDate()));
            holder.tv_driverstate_date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (position >= 1) {
            if (!timelineDateFormat.format(holder.driverState.getEventDate()).equals(timelineDateFormat.format(driverStates.get(position - 1).getEventDate()))) {
                holder.tv_driverstate_date.setText(timelineDateFormat.format(holder.driverState.getEventDate()));
                holder.tv_driverstate_date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.tv_driverstate_date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        n = driverStates.size() - 1;
        if (position == n) {
            start_time = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            abc = driverStates.get(position).getEventDate().getTime();
            end_time = sdf.format(abc);
        } else if (position < n) {
            xyz = driverStates.get(position).getEventDate().getTime();
            abc = driverStates.get(position + 1).getEventDate().getTime();
            start_time = sdf.format(xyz);
            end_time = sdf.format(abc);
        }
        try {
            d1 = sdf.parse(start_time);
            d2 = sdf.parse(end_time);
            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            //           long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
            long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            //long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            holder.tv_deriver_since.setText(diffHours + "hr" + diffMinutes + "min");

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.tv_driveractivty_time.setText(timelineTimeFormat.format(holder.driverState.getEventDate()));
        {
            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (null != mListener) {
                        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                        mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.driverState);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        holder.tv_driverinspection.setText(driverStates.get(position).getNote());


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (driverStates != null) {
            return driverStates.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }



    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        final View mView;
        final TextView mIdView, tv_driverstate_date, tv_driveractivty_time;
        final TextView mContentView, tv_deriver_since, tv_driverinspection;
        DriverState driverState;
        TimelineView timelineView;
        LinearLayout mapViewContainer;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
            timelineView = (TimelineView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_marker);
            tv_driverstate_date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.datelist);
            tv_driveractivty_time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_timeline_time);
            tv_deriver_since = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_drivertimeline_sincehour);
            tv_driverinspection = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_drivertimeline_vehicleNote);



        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }


    public void addDriverStateTimeline(DriverState driverState) {
        driverStates.add(driverState);
        notifyItemInserted(driverStates.size() - 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: do you know the code to show a dialog? just call that code in clickListener of item in your RecyclerView. What issue are you getting in it?

Comment: i dont know the code..

Comment: then i would suggest to learn code of dialog, there are plenty of tutorials online. If any issue occurs then paste that issue there so we can help